# c++ array content changed when refereing to global array

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

I an trying to write c++ code using openGl to render Sierpinski_gasket. I have defined tow new data types using `typedef`, and then i create a pointer to one of those new datatypes:

```
typedef GLfloat point2[2]; 
typedef point2 myTriangle[3];
myTriangle *triangle;
```

I write a function `init` that takes three points, then create a new `myTriangle` and then assign it to `*triangle`

```
void init(point2 p1, point2 p2, point2 p3){  
    myTriangle t;
    t[0][0] = p1[0];
    t[0][1] = p1[1];

    t[1][0] = p2[0];
    t[1][1] = p2[1];

    t[2][0] = p3[0];
    t[2][1] = p3[1];

    triangle = &t;    
}
```

this is my `diplay` function:

```
void display(void){
    static point2 p = {1,1};
    int i;        
    //pick a random vertex    
    i = rand() % 3;  //i in the range 0 to 2

    p[0] = (p[0] + *triangle[i][0])/2;
    p[1] = (p[1] + *triangle[i][1])/2;
    cout << p[0] << ' , ' << p[1] << endl;
    //display new points
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2fv(p);
    glEnd();                
}
```

the problem is that the values of `*triangle` changes after each call to `display`.. 
Can anyone tell me why and how to fix that ?

the full code is below

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef GLfloat point2[2];
typedef point2 myTriangle[3];

myTriangle *triangle;
void init(point2 p1, point2 p2, point2 p3);
void display(void);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //initialize the GLUT library
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");

    //openGL Code
    glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glOrtho(-5.0, 15.0, -5, 15.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glPointSize(5);
    //triangle points
    point2 p1, p2, p3;

    p1[0] = 5.0;
    p1[1] = 0.0;    

    p2[0] = 10.0;
    p2[1] = 0.0;

    p3[0] = 7.5;
    p3[1] = 10.0;

    init(p1,p2,p3);
//    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
//        glVertex2fv(p1);
//        glVertex2fv(p2);
//        glVertex2fv(p3);
//    glEnd();
    for(int j=0 ; j< 10000; j++){
        display();
    }

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void init(point2 p1, point2 p2, point2 p3){  
    myTriangle t;
    t[0][0] = p1[0];
    t[0][1] = p1[1];

    t[1][0] = p2[0];
    t[1][1] = p2[1];

    t[2][0] = p3[0];
    t[2][1] = p3[1];

    triangle = &t;    
}

void display(void){
    static point2 p = {1,1};
    int i;

    //pick a random vertex    
    i = rand() % 3;  //i in the range 0 to 2

    p[0] = (p[0] + *triangle[i][0])/2;
    p[1] = (p[1] + *triangle[i][1])/2;
    cout << p[0] << ' , ' << p[1] << endl;
    //display new points
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2fv(p);
    glEnd();


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning an address of a local variable in your `init` function.  When `init` returns, that address you've assigned is no longer valid, since the variable tied to that address is local.

```
void init(point2 p1, point2 p2, point2 p3)
{  
    myTriangle t;
    t[0][0] = p1[0];
    t[0][1] = p1[1];

    t[1][0] = p2[0];
    t[1][1] = p2[1];

    t[2][0] = p3[0];
    t[2][1] = p3[1];

    triangle = &t;    // <-- assigning address of local variable.  No good.
}
```

The issue with your code is that you do not have a `myTriangle` that is alive for you to assign to the `triangle` pointer.

Your current code sets `triangle` to a `myTriangle` that is going to die off as soon as the `init` function returns, and nothing in your code indicates where this "alive" object that `triangle` will point to will exist.

So in reality, you're asking for a solution that only you can really come up with.  We can suggest things like allocate a global `myTriangle`, where the address won't get invalidated, or use `new myTriangle` within the function to dynamically allocate one (which then leads to other issues), or some other answer similar to that.  However that is a design decision you have to make.

Answer (score 4):

```
void init(point2 p1, point2 p2, point2 p3){  
    myTriangle t;
    ..
    triangle = &t;
} // Life time of 't' ends here.
```

The problem is `triangle` has reference to local variable which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: the problem still exists, but this time the values changed only after first reference and after that remain constant.

Comment: Please read the thread - [Can local variables memory be accessed outside its scope ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef GLfloat point2[2]; 
typedef GLfloat myTriangle[3][2]; // EDIT
myTriangle *triangle;
```

Compiles and runs fine, should do what you want.

Comment: it still changed after first call, i just try to print them 10 times, in the first time it print the correct value, but then they change and remain the same after that. `cout<< *triangle[0][0]<<endl;` in the first time it print the correct value e.g. 0 after that it print something like 8.92822e+24
and after that in each iteration it print that value

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mahesh's answer, `*triangle[i][0]` probably doesn't do what you want. It's equivalent to `*(triangle[i][0])`. Since `triangle` points to a single triangle this is UB if `i > 0`. You need to do `(*triangle)[i][0]` instead. This will dereference the pointer first.